# Return Records based on ID(search in textchanged event) column and (ISActive=true) column value(ASP.NET))

Tags: asp.net

i am having a table Item(ItemId,ItemCode,ItemName,CategoryId,IsActive) columns.
i have a textbox for all columns.when i enter ItemId..in (txtItemId) textbox..all records based on that id should be filled in remaining textboxes for other columns.its working fine for itemid search.but my requirement is i want to filter only those records based on ItemId column with IsActive=1(true) i.e(filtering based on two columns).so,i want a query in ado.net (application level).The below query doesn't work.

```
strSqlCommand = "Select * from Item1 where ItemId=" + txtItemId.Text.Trim()" and IsActive="1";
```

Comment: You're missing a space after `txtItemId.Text.Trim()`

Comment: When you say you want to query in ado.net do you mean you want to write a linq query? The query you have provided looks fine. The only thing I can think is "and where item id = 1" assuming it is an integer column. Just get it to work in SQL management studio then it's virtually a copy and paste. Needless to say do not use inline queries. Use entity framework or a stored procedure or some other technique. This technique is dated and vulnerable.

Comment: thanks ....for the reply.. i found a small mistake in my inline query..and have corrected it...